# Binding Itemtemplate of GridView with DataTable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have below GridView in .aspx file.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdScopeList" runat="server">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ScopeChk" runat="server" Checked=false />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="sync_scope_name"  Visible=true />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I am using  Dataset/DataTable  for assiging the GridView.Below is the Code snippet used in PageLoad event.

```
string scopecomm="select sync_scope_name from Sync.scope_info";
DataSet ds_scope = new DataSet();
ds_scope = GetData(scopecomm, remoteconn);   grdScopeList.DataSource = ds_scope;
grdScopeList.DataBind();
```

But I am getting the column sync_scope_name **twice**.I am  able to bind the column sync_scope_name in Dataset to BoundField.I just need to show it **once**.

Regards,

Sachin K

Comment: Are you sure that GetData is not getting the  column sync_scope_name twice

Comment: Getdata is getting only single column i.e. sync_scope_name.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your query is returning duplicates.

Run your query manually against your database to discard this.

If the query **should** return duplicates and you only want to show them once, you need to group your query

```
select sync_scope_name 
from Sync.scope_info
group by sync_scope_name
```

Or use the `distinct` keyword

```
select distinct sync_scope_name from Sync.scope_info
```

Answer (score 1):

I added AutoGenerateColumns="false" in GridView.